# Outlook Rule that includes sent answers

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have created a rule in Outlook 2013 that finds all Mail received from a specific domain and marks them accordingly as I want to categorize my incoming mails by projects / companies.

Unfortunately, only the mails I received are found. How do I modify the rule to also include my answers to these mails? Do I really have to create a second rule for all my rules to include my answers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to create a second *"Apply rule on messages I send"* rule.

Moreover, if you need to retain categories for outgoing messages, you'll need to enable support for it in Outlook and Exchange Server.

In Outlook 2003+ you need to edit registry as follows:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\XX.0\Outlook\Preferences
DWORD: SendPersonalCategories = 1
```

Where **XX** is the Outlook version number (from **10** for Outlook 2003 to **15** for Outlook 2013).

In Exchange Server 2007+ you need to execute the following PowerShell command:

```
Set-TransportConfig -ClearCategories $False
```

This will prevent clearing categories on sent messages.

Comment: Do you mean I have to execute a command on the Exchange Server itself? If so, this is not possible as the exchange serve is administered by my companie's IT departement

Comment: Yes, you need to prevent the Exchange to clear message categories for outgoing messages (outside your organization) by executing the command on a server. If you only need these categories inside the organization, you don't need to configure the server, just tweak the registry. By the way, categories will be stored in your Sent Items anyway: Exchange clears them after send for external messages only.